# Which animal symbolises trade?

Tags: creative-writing, word-choice

Different animals symbolise different objects or actions. For example:

1. Bird for letter or postman.
2. Horse for speed and power.
3. Bull for aggressivitet and anger.

Im looking for an animal or plant/tree which can symbolise market, store, trade, or commerce?

PS! if you have other objects that can symbolise commerce or trade, please post. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Writers SE. We take questions about writing and editing. This is not on-topic for our site as written. If you want to reframe it as a writing question ("I am creating a fantasy universe where my characters are turned into animals which symbolize their inner flaws" or something), it may work. We need context to make this appropriate for the board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic symbol for trade is a standing set of scales, standing (as opposed to handheld/hanging, more frequently associated with justice).

If you want an animal, the one most frequently associated with trade will be the camel. While there were other animals used to transport wares for trade, about all of them served primarily in different roles like farming, rapid travel, military. Meanwhile, camels were primarily traders' animals, all their other uses quite secondary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look at the genre and also the time period to make the symbolism more effective. Just be aware that many of the symbols mentioned in the answers may have historical or cultural significance that may or may not apply to the potential audience and story that you are writing.